# How to avoid portion of rectangle from scrolling through ScrollWindow concept?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, user32

I have analyzed and rendered different image objects with the nested containers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-nested-graphics-containers.

Please refer to image for example. [image: Nested painting]

The inner red rectangle should be always rendered at the same position and i do some rendering outside the form which can be scrollable.

For scrolling, i am using the native methods **ScrollWindowEx**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
internal static extern bool ScrollWindowEx(IntPtr hWnd, int xAmount, int yAmount, ref NativePaint.RECT rectScrollRegion, ref NativePaint.RECT rectClip, IntPtr hrgnUpdate, ref NativePaint.RECT prcUpdate, int flags);
```

When i scroll the window to left, then the inner left rectangle also moves to left.

So i there any options available only to scroll the outer regions apart from the inner graphics container?

Please let me know, how to **avoid scrolling of the graphics container portion**?

Comment: Interesting link. But the Tag is certainly wrong, as it refers to an Apple technology. - You could translatetranform the graphics object, but i'm not sure what you are actually doing, just a form and drawrectangle calls to its graphics object? Or are any other controls nested?

Comment: @TaW - I am rendering the nested images in a control and scrolling and i wanted to achieve the above described in control rendering.